# How can I get the primary key of an updated row in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

In a database with the two tables `users` and `apples`, I want to assign an apple to a user, and know the apple id afterwards. Multiple apples can be assigned to one user. I work in PHP.

```
// users asks for an apple - lets find a vacant one
$apple_id = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM apple WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1")->fetchColumn();

// hope fully we found an apple, lets assign it
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE apple SET user_id = ? WHERE apple_id = ?");
$sth->execute(array($user_id,apple_id));
```

The problem is that another transaction could choose the same apple, and then one user would override the apple from the other.
If I include `AND user_id IS NULL` in the update statement, I run the risk of not getting an apple.

I know that I could just go with `UPDATE apple SET user_id = ? WHERE user_id IS NULL`, but then I would not know the apple id afterwards.

Is there a way to get the primary key of an updated row? 
Something like `lastUpdatedId` would be nice.

But I think I have to use a transaction. But which Isolation level do I have to choose? Repeatable read? Serializeable? And why? And what are the implications of this? Will it lock only the row or the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
update apple
    set user_id = if(@apple_id := apple_id, ?, ?)
    where user_id is null
    limit 1;

select @apple_id;
```

Comment: yeah, that looks reat! however, I just found the `FOR UPDATE`  select mode, which appears to exatly what I wanted

Comment: @Surrican . . . Just be careful using `for update`.  The back-and-forth to the application is quite time consuming in database time, which results in the locks being held for a longer period of time (not to mention the fun stuff that can happen if you are waiting for user input or have some other error).

Comment: can you just explain your solution. am I correct in assuming that you just use the if statement to assign the id from the current row to avaiable, and both `?` placehoders hold the same value (user_id)? so the if statement is actually only "mis used" to execute the variable assignment? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: And actually the assignment should aways return true, so if(@apple_id := apple_id, ?, null) should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ... FOR UPDATE will produce exactly the desired effect:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

// users asks for an apple - lets find a vacant one
$apple_id = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM apple WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE")->fetchColumn();

// hope fully we found an apple, lets assign it
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE apple SET user_id = ? WHERE apple_id = ?");
$sth->execute(array($user_id,apple_id));

$dbh->commit();
```

The second transaction will wait until the first has commited.